# How is it possible to create instance of IList?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# I understand that one cannot create an instance of an interface:

```
> new IList<double>()
(1,1): error CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IList<double>'
```

But today I saw the following code:

```
> new IList<double>[3]
IList<double>[3] { null, null, null }
```

Isn't that strange! How is this possible?

In particular, how can null be an element, when double is non-nullable?

```
> new List<double> { null }
(1,20): error CS1950: The best overloaded Add method 'List<double>.Add(double)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
(1,20): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from '<null>' to 'double'
```

What's going on?

Comment: That is similar to `double[3]` in that you create an array that will hold `double` and the array is 3 elements in size. The only difference here is the containing type, the array in your question is of `IList<double>` (instead of `double`).

Comment: It's not strange. The first snippet tried creating an instance of an interface which is impossible. The second one tried to create an array of `IList<double>` items filled with default values, ie `null`. The *third* one tried to store a `null` in a container meant to hold `double` instances

Comment: Whoever voted to close is incorrect. It's not a simple typographical error because the querent doesn't understand the effects of the syntax they've stumbled upon and has a question about the effect of that.

Comment: @JonHanna No, this is not someone who doesn't know what an array is (if it was, it'd be a duplicate, by the way).  This is someone who just didn't notice that they were creating an array instead of an `IList` (i.e. a simple typographical error).  You apparently have a *really* low opinion of the OP otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have there is an array of IList, which is full of null. Consider:

```
new IList<double>[3] { new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 }, null, null }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't recognise `IList<double>[3]` as an array of lists.

Answer (score 4):

`new IList<double>[3]` creates an `new IList<double>[]`, that is to say an array where the elements are each `new IList<double>`.

So for example you could do:

```
var arr = new IList<double>[3];
arr[0] = new List<double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking carefully at the output, you can distinguish one and two dimensional data structures.

A simple list (one dimensional):

```
> new List<string> { null, null, null }
List<string>(3) { null, null, null }
```

An array of lists (two dimensional):

```
> new IList<string>[3]
IList<string>[3] { null, null, null }
```

In square brackets, 3 indicates the length of an array. In round brackets, 3 indicates the length of a list.